# Creating a mother/child program in python

Tags: python-3.x, network-programming, powershell-3.0

My original concept is that i would have a mother program controlling the child programs installed on some (possible up to 5) computers. The child programs job would be to take commands from the mother program and execute those commands on their host computers. I know for this project my program would need to deal with ip addresses. I also know it will have to interact with the windows command promt/powershell. If anyone can give me advice on where to start it would be very much appreciated! Google doesnt return much on this topic for some reason. Thanks people!

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest thing would be when the host of your mother program has a fixed IP or DNS.

Then your clients could simply connect back to your mother program.

It sounds a bit like a reverse shell you want to program here and I want to mention that according to German Law already the programming of this is illegal. Probably this is the reason why you don't find much about the topic.

Comment: Thanks for that advice, and that bit about german law makes sense, im just doing this because my Grandma and a few other family members have problems which largely can be solved  via the command line, this would just save me having to go to their house to do it! I have found a few examples doing some of what i want to do and am having sucess with those,  but program still really bare bones at the moment.